# Form Validation Help

Tags: validation

I have a SharePoint list with a number of various columns.

One column titled **Salary Step Processing**. Whenever the value of this column is not set to **Not Required**, I require another column titled **Birthday Updates** to be set to **Automatic - Use Salary Step Processing Post Payrun**.

I was hoping to use the Validation settings to assist, but I'm not sure exactly how.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validation settings can prompt the user to set the conditionally required column with something like:

Formula:

> =IF([Salary Step Processing]<>"Not Required",IF([Birthday Updates]<>"Automatic - Use Salary Step Processing Post Payrun",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)

User Message:
Birthday Updates must be set to "Automatic - Use Salary Step Processing Post Payrun" if Salary Step Processing is required.

If you would like the column to be updated automatically when Salary Step Processing not equals Not Required, I believe that would require some code.

Comment: Hello Ornery, Thank you for replying. Helped a lot! Do you know if there is a way to add multiple verification?